# Why is featuretools creating features from my dataframe index?

Tags: python, featuretools

I've noticed that featuretools created features from my dataframe index. For example:

```
'LAST(transactions.payment_id)'
```

This is the index I set when creating the entity:

```
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'transactions', 
                              dataframe = transactions,
                              make_index=True,
                              index = 'payment_id',
                              time_index = 'local_date')
```

What is the use in creating features from an index? And if there is no use in this, how can this be disabled? I trained a model overnight and found that payment ID was a very important feature which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the index is used to generate features. This can be avoided by using the `drop_contains` parameter. So, the DFS call would look something like this:

```py
ft.dfs(
    ...
    drop_contains=['payment_id'],
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes I figured out the `drop_contains` parameter. But I'd still like to know why the `id` column is used to create features. Is there any scenario where this is useful?

Comment: I haven't come across a specific scenario. I'd imagine they can be used to build more entities.